# XSLT Match - match failing to work for <xsl:template match="date">

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="dateofbirth">
```

matches fine against my original xml document

```
<parent>
    <dateofbirth>19750201</dateofbirth>
</parent>
```

however

```
<xsl:template match="date">
```

fails to match against

```
<parent>
    <date>20051212</date>
</parent>
```

I can't change the xml schema, is there something special about using the word date that breaks standard xslt matching rules, and if so can anybody recommend a work-around that doesn't involve changing the xml?

I am using XSLT 2.0 with saxon engine

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, apparently the word date by itself will not be causing problems and therefore I can assume my code is broken. Apologies for the bad phrasing of the question, I was really only interested in whether the word date is a special case (a reserved word) which it isn't

Comment: "*is there something special about using the word date*" No. The problem is somewhere in the parts of the code (XML and/or XSLT) that you **haven't** posted.

Comment: Try using `*:date`. If that matches, you have a default namespace somewhere else in your XML. If it still doesn't match, like @michael.hor257k said, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Also, if elsewhere you have an `<xsl:apply-templates select="dateofbirth" />` or something similar (in a loop with `xsl:for-each` for instance) then you will have to rename that as well. Or, if you like a-point help, show a minimized input document and stylesheet that makes it possible for us to reproduce your issue. See also [ask].

Comment: ok my question was fairly specific and has been answered then thank you I can't seem to mark this as answered however

Comment: "*I can't seem to mark this as answered*" That's because technically it hasn't been answered yet, merely commented upon. I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there something special about using the word date

No. The problem is somewhere in the parts of the code (XML and/or XSLT) that you haven't posted.